# Linux: is there a way to use ptrace without stopping/pausing the process (SIGSTOP)?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, process, ptrace

I'm trying to port a program from Windows to Linux.
I encountered a problem when I found out that there isn't a "real" `ReadProcessMemory` counterpart on Linux; I searched for an alternative and I found `ptrace`, a powerful process debugger.
I quickly coded two small console applications in C++ to test `ptrace`, before using it in the program.

**TestApp**

This is the tracee; it keeps printing two integers every 50 milliseconds while increasing their value by 1 every time.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sleeper : public QThread
{
public:
    static void usleep(unsigned long usecs){QThread::usleep(usecs);}
    static void msleep(unsigned long msecs){QThread::msleep(msecs);}
    static void sleep(unsigned long secs){QThread::sleep(secs);}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    int value = 145;
    int i = 0;

    do {
    cout << "i: " << i << " " << "Value: " << value << endl;
    value++;
    i++;
    Sleeper::msleep(50);
    } while (true);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**MemoryTest**

This is the tracer; it asks for the process name and retrieves the PID using the command `pidof -s`, then `ptrace` attaches to the process and retrieves the memory address' value every 500 milliseconds, for 10 times.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

class Sleeper : public QThread
{
public:
    static void usleep(unsigned long usecs){QThread::usleep(usecs);}
    static void msleep(unsigned long msecs){QThread::msleep(msecs);}
    static void sleep(unsigned long secs){QThread::sleep(secs);}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    char process_name[50];
    cout << "Process name: ";
    cin >> process_name;

    char command[sizeof(process_name) + sizeof("pidof -s ")];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "pidof -s %s", process_name);

    FILE* shell = popen(command, "r");
    char pidI[sizeof(shell)];
    fgets(pidI, sizeof(pidI), shell);
    pclose(shell);

    pid_t pid = atoi(pidI);
    cout << "The PID is " << pid << endl;

    long status = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    cout << "Status: " << status << endl;
    cout << "Error: " << errno << endl;

    unsigned long addr = 0x012345; // Example address, not the true one
    int i = 0;
    do {
    status = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, addr, NULL);
    cout << "Status: " << status << endl;
    cout << "Error: " << errno << endl;
    i++;
    Sleeper::msleep(500);
    } while (i < 10);

    status = ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    cout << "Status: " << status << endl;
    cout << "Error: " << errno << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Everything works fine, but TestApp is paused (SIGSTOP) until `ptrace` detaches from it.
Also, when it attaches to the process, the status is 0 and the error is 2; the first time it tries to retrieve the memory address value it fails with status -1 and error 3. Is it normal?
Is there a way to prevent ptrace from sending the SIGSTOP signal to the process?
I already tried using `PTRACE_SEIZE` instead of `PTRACE_ATTACH`, but it doesn't work: status -1 and error 3.

**Update:** Using `Sleeper` in MemoryTest before the "do-while" loop fixes the problem of the first memory address value retrieval, even if the value of seconds, milliseconds or microseconds is 0. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of research I'm pretty sure that there isn't a way to use `ptrace` without stopping the process.
I found a real `ReadProcessMemory` counterpart, called `process_vm_readv`, which is much more simple.

I'm posting the code in the hope of helping someone who is in my (previous) situation.

Many thanks to **[mkrautz](https://github.com/mkrautz/)** for his help coding MemoryTest with this beautiful function.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sleeper : public QThread
{
public:
    static void usleep(unsigned long usecs){QThread::usleep(usecs);}
    static void msleep(unsigned long msecs){QThread::msleep(msecs);}
    static void sleep(unsigned long secs){QThread::sleep(secs);}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    char process_name[50];
    cout << "Process name: ";
    cin >> process_name;

    char command[sizeof(process_name) + sizeof("pidof -s ")];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "pidof -s %s", process_name);

    FILE* shell = popen(command, "r");
    char pidI[sizeof(shell)];
    fgets(pidI, sizeof(pidI), shell);
    pclose(shell);

    pid_t pid = atoi(pidI);

    cout << "The PID is " << pid << endl;

    if (pid == 0)
        return false;

    struct iovec in;
    in.iov_base = (void *) 0x012345; // Example address, not the true one
    in.iov_len = 4;

    uint32_t foo;

    struct iovec out;
    out.iov_base = &foo;
    out.iov_len = sizeof(foo);

    do {
        ssize_t nread = process_vm_readv(pid, &out, 1, &in, 1, 0);
        if (nread == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: %s", strerror(errno));
        } else if (nread != in.iov_len) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: short read of %li bytes", (ssize_t)nread);
        }
        cout << foo << endl;
        Sleeper::msleep(500);
    } while (true);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I have looking for something similar but for a different purpose, I have been looking for peeking into stack. Now linux does have /proc/{pid}/stack but the linux system I have to make the program for doesn't and I can't halt the process.

Comment: I would look for `[stack]` in _/proc/{pid}/maps_. The line could be, for example:

`7ffd44730000-7ffd44751000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]`

The two addresses (start and end, respectively) define the memory area that is available to the specified module (in this case the stack).

You can use `process_vm_readv()` to read the area.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying make like a basic debugging application, process stack isn't of much help in my case. I discovered strace which also uses` ptrace()` but only when it makes a `syscall`, it does slow down process a bit but since we are debugging I suppose it's fair.  I am trying make my own version of `strace` now for it to work on the embedded system, which will require a new research now.

Answer (score 4):

Davide,

Have you had a look at the /proc filesystem?  It contains memory map files that can be used to peek at the full process space.   You can also write in the space to set a breakpoint.  There is a wealth of other information in /proc as well.

The PTRACE_CONT command can be used to continue a process.  Generally, the target will be paused with a PTRACE_ATTACH when the debugger attaches.

The man page says PTRACE_SIEZE should not pause the process.  What flavor and version of Linux are you using?  PTRACE_SIEZE has been around for quite awhile so I'm not sure why you are having trouble there.

I note the addr value is set to 0x12345.  Is this a valid address in the target space? Or was that just an example?  How is the stack address of interest (&value) communicated between the two processes?

I'm not too sure about the return codes.  Generally a 0 means all is well, the errno may just be a hangover value from the last error.

--Matt

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't take a look at /proc, because I would like to use a simpler method; if it isn't possible, I will try with the memory map files. I'm using Debian 8 x64, this should not be the problem; my guess is that `PTRACE_SEIZE` needs to be used in a different way from `PTRACE_ATTACH`, but I can't find any specific documentation.

Comment: Sorry for the two comments, I pressed Enter thinking that it breaks the line; I edited the comment but it can't be updated anymore after 5 minutes. The `addr` value is just an example, the correct one works fine. About the error codes, they should not be a problem, because the program works fine.

Comment: Don't worry, I specified that it was an example after your answer; I voted it. I didn't try to use `PTRACE_CONT` because it wouldn't solve my problem, as it just resumes the process without the need of `PTRACE_DETACH`, while I need to attach `ptrace` to the process without stopping it.